# How can I create this table using html only?

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image]

What I tried the result were  not as expected the above two columns i.e. 'soldby' & 'date' were not equal, when I tried manually giving width it was messing everything else. I saw a youtube tutorial he forcefully did it by giving hardcoded padding to table but I don't want it

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table width="500">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <td colspan="10">soldby</td>
      <td colspan="10">date</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="20">name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="20">Address</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">Cash</td>
    <td colspan="4">Change</td>
    <td colspan="4">COD</td>
    <td colspan="4">On Acct</td>
    <td colspan="4">Estimate</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="13"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="20">recivedby</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Um.....`width: 50%;`?

Comment: Stop thinking of that collection of lines as a table. There’s a table in there ( its the grid of cells with nothing written in them). Then it just has some related (but non-tabular) data arranged in boxes which are touching the table (both above and below). Write semantic markup. HTML tables are not designed to deal with columns that don’t line up with each other.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, just have a full width cell and then put another table in there that you can style however you need separately. Looks pretty close to that image! Some styles might need to be added to prevent the borders on the inner table cells from making them look thicker.

I also added `border-collapse:collapse` to merge the doubled borders, but feel free to take that out.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  height: 20px;
}

.nested-table-container {
  padding:0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table width="500">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <td colspan="10">soldby</td>
      <td colspan="10">date</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="20">name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="20">Address</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">Cash</td>
    <td colspan="4">Change</td>
    <td colspan="4">COD</td>
    <td colspan="4">On Acct</td>
    <td colspan="4">Estimate</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="20" class="nested-table-container">
      <table width="100%">
        <colgroup>
          <col/>
          <col width="70%"/>
          <col/>
          <col/>
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="20">recivedby</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you explain me this part:
```
<colgroup>
          <col/>
          <col width="70%"/>
          <col/>
          <col/>
        </colgroup>

Comment: The `<col>` elements represent the table columns. You can't see them but it's an easy way to set the width of a column without having to set the width on a `<td>` element instead.